# Bootstrap 4 - Justify content inside ul element

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

hi i m using bootstrap 4 and wanted to know how to fix "justify-content-around" property if there is more then 3 li elements it workg great but if there is =<3 it doesnt works any tips ?

content is inside this

```
<ul class="row center justify-content-around">

</ul>
```

Live example :  http://snowfox.sk/nnm/public/

Comment: Use class d-flex instead of center https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: center is my custom class it just put margin auto

Comment: and d-flex doesnt works tried it right now

Comment: Can you add working code to https://jsfiddle.net/? coz In live site we can't change the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add `style="flex-grow: 1;"` to `ul`

or

Change your code like this(check in full page)

remove the width `width: 20rem;` and add `col-4` to `li`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
<ul class="row center justify-content-around">
<li class="col-lg-4">
<div class="card card-edited" style="">
<span class="badge badge-dark card-lang">SK</span>
<img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="http://snowfox.sk/nnm/public/img/anime/12675B.jpg" alt="Obŕazok neexistuje" height="350">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title" style="overflow-y: hidden;">Natsume Yuujinchou</h4>
<p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success"><span class="fa fa-play"> Pozrieť preklad</span></a>
</div>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
<li class="list-group-item">
 <a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Google</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Mega.co.nz</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Ulož.to</a>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
 <a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Google</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Mega.co.nz</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Ulož.to</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="card-footer text-muted">
2 days ago
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-4">
<div class="card card-edited" style="">
<span class="badge badge-dark card-lang">SK</span>
<img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="http://snowfox.sk/nnm/public/img/anime/12675B.jpg" alt="Obŕazok neexistuje" height="350">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title" style="overflow-y: hidden;">Natsume Yuujinchou</h4>
<p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success"><span class="fa fa-play"> Pozrieť preklad</span></a>
</div>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
<li class="list-group-item">
 <a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Google</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Mega.co.nz</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Ulož.to</a>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
 <a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Google</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Mega.co.nz</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Ulož.to</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="card-footer text-muted">
2 days ago
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-4">
<div class="card card-edited" style="">
<span class="badge badge-dark card-lang">SK</span>
<img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="http://snowfox.sk/nnm/public/img/anime/12675B.jpg" alt="Obŕazok neexistuje" height="350">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title" style="overflow-y: hidden;">Natsume Yuujinchou</h4>
<p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success"><span class="fa fa-play"> Pozrieť preklad</span></a>
</div>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
<li class="list-group-item">
 <a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Google</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Mega.co.nz</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Ulož.to</a>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
 <a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Google</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Mega.co.nz</a> |
<a href=""><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Ulož.to</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="card-footer text-muted">
2 days ago
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Below using `d-flex` and `justify-content-around`.

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul class="d-flex justify-content-around">
  <li>Flex</li>
  <li>Flex</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will the result you want if you wrap your list in a column:

```
<div class="col">
  <ul class="row center justify-content-around">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```